# Ubuntu Server 18.04 suppress DHCP gateway

Tags: networking, server, dhcp

I want to enable DHCP on an interface only to receive network address only, no gateway.

I Ubuntu Server 16.10 this was possible by creating the file /etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d/no-default-route:

```
case $reason in
  BOUND|RENEW|REBIND|REBOOT)
    if [ $interface = enp0s8 ]; then
      unset new_routers
    fi
    ;;
esac
```

However, in Ubuntu Server 18.04, this no longer works. It's as if dhclient is not used at all.

How is this supposed to be done in Ubuntu Server 18.04 ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
First remove the entry from /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml, and then create /etc/systemd/network/no-route.network file:

```
[Match]
Name=enp0*

[Network]
DHCP=yes

[DHCP]
UseRoutes=false
```